# ¿Cómo puedo depurar una función en Dev-C++?

Tags: c++, funciones, dev-c++, depuración

he intentado entender una **función**, y para entenderla he intentado **depurarla** en **dev-c++**, y me sale este error:

```
->->breakpoints-invalid
Breakpoint 1 at 0x401569: file main.cpp, line 27.
```

**He investigado por otras partes,** pero no me han ayudado.

Entonces, ¿cuál es la manera correcta de depurar una función en Dev-C++?

Comment: No entiendo la popularidad actual de dev-cpp... un IDE cuyo desarrollo se abandonó hace 15 años. Cada tanto alguien intenta revivir el proyecto, pero al gozar de abandono y de poca mano de obra, su mantenimiento deja muchísimo que desear... yo de ti probaría CodeBlocks

Comment: @eferion La popularidad radica en que muchas universidades, en sus primeros cursos de programacion (introduccion a la programacion y programacion) te enseñan con c/c++, asi que, es el mas "facil" o mas "popular". para aprender a desarrollar.

Comment: @EdgarGc dev-cpp **no es** c++. Es simplemente un IDE pensado para programar en C++. Pero al igual que usas Dev-cpp podrías usar CodeBlocks, QtCreator, VisualStudio, VisualStudioCode, ...

Comment: En cualquier caso, en el  mismo momento en el que vas a a la web oficial de dev-cpp y ves que la última versión es compatible con Windows95... da que pensar

Comment: Ese error no es del **compilador**, ¿o si?

Comment: Es posible... piensa que dev-cpp usa un compilador de hace 15 años... es probable que no funcione correctamente con las últimas versiones de Windows

Comment: Que recuerdos de principio de programación, aun se usa el viejo y odiado dev, con respecto al error si amenos mostraras el contenido de la linea 27 del archivo main.

Comment: No creo que use el compilador por defecto de dev-cpp, normalmente te recomiendan bajarte el compilador `MinGW`. Si no lo tienes descargado, te dejo el [link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/).

Comment: @EdgarGc dudo que alguien que opta a descargarse dev-cpp "_por comodidad_" se tome la molestias de buscar la última versión del mingw para no usar el compilador que viene por defecto...

Comment: No recomiendo MinGW ni Dev-Cpp, lo ideal (para mí) es CLang de LLVM y un buen editor de texto.

Comment: Ok, gracias a todos, probaré codeblocks entonces...